# Why is the javascript slidetoggle function not staying open?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggle

I have a link on a page that toggles the search form on and off. For example you search for Spring term classes and then you want to search for a new term and click Start a new Search.  The link works great and toggles just fine...EXCEPT the toggle automatically closes again. I can't figure out why this is happening, I have searched the stack overflow site and none of the solutions seems to work (Or maybe I am still doing something wrong) Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the part that calls the function

```
<div class="course-schedule-wrapper">
    <span <?= ($show_form) ? 'style="display:none;"' : null ?> class="toggle-search"><a href="#">Start a new schedule search</a></span>
    <div id="course-schedule-search" <?= ($show_form) ? null : 'style="display:none;"' ?>>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="/schedules/">
            <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1" />
            <table summary="Course schedule search options" id="course-schedule-form">
                <tbody>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <label for="area_id" class="label">Semester:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <!--<input type="radio" name="semester" value="2014SP" id="S2014SP" checked="checked">
                            <label class="inline" for="S2014SP">Spring 2014</label>
                            <br />
-->                         <?
                            $sflag = FALSE;
                            $fflag = FALSE;
                            if ($_POST['semester'] == '2014SU'){
                                $sflag = "checked=checked";
                            } 

                            if ($_POST['semester'] == '2014FA'){
                                $fflag = "checked=checked";
                            }

                            if(!$sflag && !$fflag) {
                                $fflag = "checked=checked";
                            } 
                            ?>

                            <input type="radio" name="semester" value="2014FA" id="S2014FA" <?= $fflag; ?>>
                            <label class="inline" for="S2014FA">Fall 2014</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="semester" value="2015SP" id="S2015SP" <?= $sflag; ?>>
                            <label class="inline" for="S2014SU">Spring 2015</label>
                            <br />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <label for="text" class="label">Search for:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="text" id="text" size="60" value="<?= ( (isset($_POST['text']) ) ? $_POST['text'] : null )?>">
                            &nbsp;
                            <div class="formtext">in course ID, title, or instructor</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <label for="area_id" class="label">Area of study:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="area_id" size="1" id="area_id">

                                <option value="-1">Any Area of Study</option>

                                <?php
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM areas WHERE inactive=0 ORDER BY name";
                                    $result = db_query($query)->fetchAll();
                                ?>

                                <? foreach( $result as $area ): ?>
                                    <option <?= ( isset($_POST['area_id']) && $area->id == $_POST['area_id'] ) ?' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="<?=$area->id?>"><?= $area->name ?></option>
                                <? endforeach; ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <label for="division_id" class="label">Division:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="division_id" size="1" id="division_id">

                                <option value="-1">Any Division</option>

                                <?php
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM divisions ORDER BY name";
                                    $result = db_query($query)->fetchAll();
                                ?>

                                <? foreach( $result as $division ): ?>
                                    <option <?= ( isset($_POST['division_id']) && $division->id == $_POST['division_id'] ) ?' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="<?= $division->id ?>"><?= $division->name ?></option>
                                <? endforeach; ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <label for="time1" class="label">Start time:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="formtext">from
                                <select name="time[0]" size="1" id="time1" onchange="document.form.online.checked=false;">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">anytime</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '07:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="07:30">7:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '08:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="08:30">8:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '09:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="09:30">9:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '10:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="10:30">10:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '11:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="11:30">11:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '12:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="12:30">12:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '13:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="13:30">1:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '14:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="14:30">2:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '15:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="15:30">3:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '16:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="16:30">4:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '17:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="17:30">5:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '18:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="18:30">6:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '19:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="19:30">7:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '20:30' == $_POST['time'][0]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="20:30">8:30 PM</option>
                                </select>

                                <label for="time2">to</label>
                                <select name="time[1]" size="1" id="time2" onchange="document.form.online.checked=false;">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">anytime</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '07:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="07:30">7:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '08:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="08:30">8:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '09:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="09:30">9:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '10:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="10:30">10:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '11:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="11:30">11:30 AM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '12:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="12:30">12:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '13:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="13:30">1:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '14:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="14:30">2:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '15:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="15:30">3:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '16:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="16:30">4:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '17:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="17:30">5:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '18:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="18:30">6:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '19:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="19:30">7:30 PM</option>
                                    <option <?= (isset($_POST['time']) && '20:30' == $_POST['time'][1]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="20:30">8:30 PM</option>
                                </select>

                                (inclusive)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <label for="duration" class="label">Duration:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="duration" size="1" id="duration" onchange="document.form.online.checked=false;">
                                <option value="-1" selected="selected">any duration</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '01:00' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="01:00">1 hour</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '01:30' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="01:30">1.5 hours</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '02:00' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="02:00">2 hours</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '02:30' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="02:30">2.5 hours</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '03:00' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="03:00">3 hours</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '03:30' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="03:30">3.5 hours</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '04:00' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="04:00">4 hours</option>
                                <option <?= (isset($_POST['duration']) && '04:30' == $_POST['duration']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?> value="04:30">4.5 hours</option>
                            </select>

                            <select name="durcomp" size="1" id="durcomp" onchange="document.form.online.checked=false;">
                                <option value="less"  <?= (isset($_POST['durcomp']) && 'less' == $_POST['durcomp']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?>>or less</option>
                                <option value="more"  <?= (isset($_POST['durcomp']) && 'more' == $_POST['durcomp']) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?>>or more</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="label">Days:</td>
                        <td>
                            <table summary="Days of the week">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center"><label for="M" class="formtext">M</label></td>
                                        <td align="center"><label for="T" class="formtext">T</label></td>
                                        <td align="center"><label for="W" class="formtext">W</label></td>
                                        <td align="center"><label for="R" class="formtext">R</label></td>
                                        <td align="center"><label for="F" class="formtext">F</label></td>
                                        <td align="center"><label for="S" class="formtext">S</label></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr valign="top">
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="M" id="M" <?=( isset($_POST['M']) && "ON" == $_POST['M'] ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null ?> value="ON">
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="T" id="T" <?=( isset($_POST['T']) && "ON" == $_POST['T'] ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null ?> value="ON">
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="W" id="W" <?=( isset($_POST['W']) && "ON" == $_POST['W'] ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null ?> value="ON">
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="R" id="R" <?=( isset($_POST['R']) && "ON" == $_POST['R'] ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null ?> value="ON">
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="F" id="F" <?=( isset($_POST['F']) && "ON" == $_POST['F'] ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null ?> value="ON">
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="S" id="S" <?=( isset($_POST['S']) && "ON" == $_POST['S'] ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null ?> value="ON">
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="left">
                                            <select name="dayop" size="1" id="dayop">
                                                <option value="AND" <?=( isset($_POST['dayop']) && "AND" == $_POST['dayop'] ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?>>these days only</option>
                                                <option value="OR" <?=( isset($_POST['dayop']) && "OR" == $_POST['dayop'] ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null ?>>at least these days</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><label for="online" class="label">Show online<br>courses only:</label></td>
                        <?php 
                        if($_POST['online'] == "ON") {
                            $oflag = "checked=checked";
                        } 
                        ?>

                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="online" id="online" onclick="rst()" value="ON" <?= $oflag; ?>></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="currentcourse" id="inprog" value="3">
            <br>
            <input type="submit"> | <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>

        </form>

        <hr />

        <p class="body"><strong>To register</strong>, or for more information, contact
            the <a href="../ar/">Admissions office</a> at
            217.443.8800.
        </p>

        <p class="body">Some courses have flexible schedules or have schedules that are yet to be
            determined; these are listed as TBA (To Be Arranged) and include online
            (Internet) courses, video telecourses, internships, et cetera.  If you
            search based on time, length and/or day, the results will <b>not</b>
            include such courses.
        </p>

        <p class="body">Some courses involve a lab portion that meets at a different time and/or
            on different days than the lecture portion.  If you search based on time,
            length and/or day, the results may include the lecture portion or the lab
            portion, but not necessarily both, even though both portions are
            required.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the function information (other functions included just to make sure I am not missing anything)

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#header-logo').click(function(){
        window.location = 'http://local.dannew.com/';
    });

    $(".course-schedule-wrapper .toggle-search a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#course-schedule-search").slideToggle();
    });

    $("#quicklinks").change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() != "0" )
            window.location = $(this).val();
    });

    $(".show-in-progress").click(function(){
        $('#inprog').val('1');
        $("form[name='form']").submit();
        console.log('test');
    });

    $("a").each(function(i, el){
        if( $(el).attr('href') == "/%23" || $(el).attr('href') == "..." ){
            $(el).click(function(){
                return false;
            }).css({
                "text-decoration" : "none",
                "color" : "#000",
                "cursor" : "default"
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: A simplified version of your scenario doesn't show the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/pd8Lxm0s/). The problem may be somewhere else. Is there more Javascript?

Comment: there was one more function but that was for something different on the schedules page which was to show the courses that were already in progress.

Comment: @bobdye I am not sure why it worked without the form attached.

Comment: Try posting the entire HTML for the #course-schedule-search div. Maybe there's some non-obvious interaction.

Comment: @bobdye Added to main post

Comment: Hmm. Nothing obvious. What is the name of the file where you have your Javascript? The page is getting a 404 on http://www.dacc.edu/schedules/dacc.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72276/discussion-between-inky1231-and-bobdye).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, there was an extraneous copy of the script

```
$(".course-schedule-wrapper .toggle-search a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#course-schedule-search").slideToggle();
    });
```

in one of the other files that feeds into the page. removed that copy and now it is working great! For the record this was not as simple as it sounds as for this "schedules" page the developers created 6 different files to feed this one page!

Answer (score 0):

One click handler for that selector submits a form. Submitting a form will reload a new page based on criteria set in the `action` url code, unless the form is submitted via ajax.

There is no page state saved when you load a new page.

Thus you are basically seeing the page reset itself to a new version

Comment: The only handler that does a submit seems to be for a different selector.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for replying. How do I fix that? I confess I don't know much about javascript. This was built by someone else and I am trying to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: depends on what expectations are regarding the form. If you want the page state to remain , look into using ajax to submit form

Comment: @bobdye both events occur on `$(".show-in-progress")`, granted the toggle is on a different selector but it is triggered by the click handler

Comment: Now the code has been changed, maybe I focused on wrong events. A demo would help

Comment: @charlietti the function I am referring to is `$(".course-schedule-wrapper .toggle-search a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#course-schedule-search").slideToggle();
    });` you can check it out by doing a search on www.dacc.edu/schedules then click start a new schedule search